# In PHP, can i use put echo inside a variable?

Tags: php

I wrote this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $javascript = echo '<script type = "text/javascript">',
            'prompt("Hello");', '</script>';;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\h.php on line 7

Comment: You can't. Decide if you want to echo or assign to a variable. Or assign to the variable, the echo it out.

Comment: Echo isn't a function and doesn't  have a return value, so I'm not sure what the goal is here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say can I put echo, not use put

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE HMTL>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $javascript = '<script type = "text/javascript">prompt("Hello");</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works

Comment: `<?= "string" ?>` == `<?php echo "string" ?>` **since PHP v5.4**

Comment: @Mihailo That's supported way before 5.4, probably since the very beginning of PHP, except the `short_open_tag` option can disable it before 5.4 as `<?=` was recognized as a special short tags case as it's easy to distinguish from XML's `<?`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @Ultimater yup I know. I didn't feel like it was necessary to write the details.  But sure now we have the details as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply echo the script using echo (without even using the variable)

```
<?php
echo '<script type = "text/javascript">prompt("Hello");</script>';
?>
```

Or Using variable

```
<?php
echo $javascript = '<script type = "text/javascript">prompt("Hello");</script>';
?>
```

Or using shorthand

```
<?='<script type = "text/javascript">prompt("Hello");</script>'?>
```